# Python discord bot screen recording feature doesn't stop recording

Tags: python, discord.py

I've added a feature to my bot where it can record my screen for a time that I specify, convert the file to mp4, and send it to the channel. Everything worked perfectly until I decided to add a countdown feature where it edits the embed and keeps displaying for how long it has been recording the screen.
Here's the code:

```
@client.command()
async def rec(ctx, dur, *, name=None):
    name = name or "RECORDING"
    resolution = (1920, 1080)
    codec = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"XVID")
    filename = "D:/Python scripts/Projects/spy/Recording.avi"
    out = cv2.VideoWriter(filename, codec, 7.0, resolution)
    cv2.namedWindow("Checking for updates", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
    cv2.resizeWindow("Checking for updates", 480, 270)
    start = time.time()
    msg = await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(color=ctx.author.color, description=f"**Recording screen\nETA: `{dur}`s**"))
    while True:
        now = time.time()
        delay = str(now-start)
        if delay.startswith(dur):
            break
        else:
            # await msg.edit(embed=discord.Embed(color=ctx.author.color, description=f"**RECORDING SCREEN**\nETA: `{delay[:3]}`s"))
            img = pyautogui.screenshot()
            frame = np.array(img)
            frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            out.write(frame)
            
        
    out.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    await msg.edit(embed=discord.Embed(color=ctx.author.color, description=f"**:hourglass: Converting file to mp4**"))
    ff = ffmpy.FFmpeg(executable='D:/Softwares/misc/FFmpeg/ffmpeg-N-101727-g2c806aa2b4-win64-gpl/bin/ffmpeg.exe', inputs={pathAvi:None}, outputs={pathMp4+name+".mp4":["-filter:a", "atempo=0.5"]})
    ff.run()
    await msg.edit(embed=discord.Embed(color=ctx.author.color, description=f"**:white_check_mark: Uploading file(`{name}.mp4`) to {ctx.message.channel.mention}**"))
    try:
        await ctx.send(file=discord.File(pathMp4+name+".mp4"))
        await msg.delete()
    except Exception as error:
        await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(color=ctx.author.color, description=f"**:x: Error:**`{error}`"))
    os.remove(pathMp4+name+".mp4")
    os.remove("D:/Python scripts/Projects/spy/Recording.avi")
```

I've commented out the line just below the `else` statement. When I comment the line, everything works the way it's supposed to; it waits for the time I specified inside the `dur` variable and breaks out of the while loop. But when I uncomment it, it just keeps editing the embed forever and never stops recording the screen.
I've tried everything I could, and yet I still couldn't find a way to fix this issue. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your while-loop you're basically editing the embed with the clockspeed of your cpu. Combined with your other code this is approx 50 times per second. Of course this is waaaaay to often. Discord rate-limits calls to the api to prevent spamming and overloading of their systems. What you encounter seems to be how discord.py handles this. You should edit the embed **at max** once per second. You'll need some logic to detect when another second has passed. It could look something like this

---

```py
    second = 0
    while True:
        now = time.time()
        delay = str(now-start)
        if delay.startswith(dur):
            break
        else:
            if int(now % 60) > (second + 1):
                await msg.edit(embed=discord.Embed(color=ctx.author.color, description=f"**RECORDING SCREEN**\nETA: `{delay[:3]}`s"))
                second = int(now % 60)
            elif int(now % 60) == 0:
                second = 0
            img = pyautogui.screenshot()
            frame = np.array(img)
            frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            out.write(frame)
```

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that most of this code is blocking and should be ran in a separate thread.